# PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/logout] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I started working on Spring Security implementation and I'm currently having problems with user logout. When I try to logout I'm receiving a 404 response:

> WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/logout] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

Here is a code of application-security.xml:

```
<form-login login-page="/loginForm"
                login-processing-url="/login"
                username-parameter="username"
                password-parameter="password"
                default-target-url="/"/>
<logout logout-url="/logout"
            logout-success-url="/loginForm"/>
```

And here is a part of jsp page responsible for logging out:

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <a href="<c:url value="/logout"/>" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Sign out</a>
</div>
```

PS: `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>` is added.
Login works great, don't get what the problem might be with logout mapping. Thanks for help.

Comment: Try post request http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108585/spring-security-java-config-not-generating-logout-url/24110187#24110187

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31297500/2324685